# How to compute the change of Ridge regression solution when one row of data changes?

Tags: ridge-regression, moving-window

I understand that $\boldsymbol{\beta} = (X^TX + \lambda I)^{-1}X^T\mathbf{
Y}$ is the closed form solution of Ridge regression.

So sometimes, when I run a rolling window, meaning everytime I run the regression, I remove one row of data and add in a new row, how do I tell how much $\beta$ has changed from this closed form solution.

Better still, is it possible for me to express the change in $\beta$ in terms of the Euclidean distance between the rows that are removed and added? Or set a lower bound for change in $\beta$ based on the Euclidean distance between the rows?

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: @ Simon Boge Brant Thank you, just edited the question.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "$X.$"  If that is intended to refer to the raw data matrix, then an efficient rolling ridge regression formula can be derived fairly easily.  But if, as is usual with ridge regression, "$X$" refers to the *centered, scaled* variables, the problem is that adding or deleting even a single observation changes every component of $X$ in a nonlinear fashion, which will substantially complicate the analysis and the formulas.

Comment: @whuber Let's assume that the data is raw, not centred nor scaled.

Answer (score 1):

### Online Moving-Window Ridge Regression

You can use this same closed-form solution to update your $\beta$ online, even in a moving-window context. Suppose you have $m$ data points $x_1, \ldots, x_m$ and m responses $y_1, \ldots, y_m$ and your moving-window size is $L \leq m$.

Note that you can rewrite the closed-form solution as $\left(\sum_{i=1}^L x_ix_i^T + \lambda I\right)^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^L y_ix_i = A^{-1}b$.

1. Initialize $A = \sum_{i=1}^L x_ix_i^T + \lambda I$ and $b = \sum_{i=1}^L y_ix_i$.
2. A new point $x_{m+1}$ comes in.
3. Set $A = A + x_{m+1}x_{m+1}^T - x_{m-L}x_{m-L}^T$. This adds the information in the new data point to $A$ while removing the information from the old data point now outside the moving window.
4. Predict $f(x_{m+1}) = b^TA^{-1}x_{m+1}$
5. Receive $y_{m+1}$
6. Update $b = b + y_{m+1}x_{m+1} - y_{m-L}x_{m-L}$

You can also use the [Sherman-Morrison formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherman%E2%80%93Morrison_formula) to update $A^{-1}$ directly instead of recomputing the inverse every time. You can see [this paper](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Paola_Arce/publication/236648230_Online_Ridge_Regression_Method_Using_Sliding_Windows/links/0c96052a7a837d2616000000/Online-Ridge-Regression-Method-Using-Sliding-Windows.pdf) for more information about online moving-window ridge regression.

### Change in $\beta$ Analytically

TBD...

Comment: Thank you, the paper is good :) May I know is it possible to write out the change in \beta analytically? Or set a analytical lower bound of change in \beta. I want to show that when the removed and the added data are not identical, the Ridge regression result will definitely change.

Comment: Intuitively, $\beta$ will not change as long as the new data point $(x_t, y_t)$ does not lie on the hyperplane that $\beta$ represents. It is possible to write out the change in $\beta$ analytically using the Sherman-Morrison formula. I'll edit my answer to include this.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much. This answer is great :) Unfortunately, I am under 15 reputations, so I upvoted you, but the vote cannot be shown publicly. I wonder whether I can show that the change in \beta is non-zero whenever the new data point differs from the old data point.

Comment: I realize that inverse of =++1+1−−− and −1−(−1(−−))(−1(−−))1+(−−)−1(−−). Any idea?

Comment: Could you write that using LaTeX formatting? It's hard to read in plain text.

Comment: $A+x_{m+1}x_{m+1}^T-x_{m-L}x_{m-L}^T$ is not the same as $A+(x_{m+1}-x_{m-L})(x_{m+1}-x_{m-L})^T$. So in the second segment of your answer, the expression of $\beta_{t+1}$ is incorrect.

Comment: You're right. My bad. I'll remove it until I can fix it.

Comment: Before you work too hard at this, please consider the comment I posted to the question.